# find where values in one numpy array fall between values in another numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a more numpythonic way to do this?

```
#example arrays
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=np.float32)
values = np.array([0.2, 3.0, 1.5])

#get the indices where each value falls between values in arr
between = [np.nonzero(i > arr)[0][-1] for i in values]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sorted `arr`, we can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for performance -

```
In [67]: np.searchsorted(arr,values)-1
Out[67]: array([0, 2, 1])
```

Timings on large dataset -

```
In [81]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: arr = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,10000, 10000))
    ...: values = np.random.randint(0,10000, 1000)

# @Andy L.'s soln
In [84]: %timeit np.argmin(values > arr[:,None], axis=0) - 1
10 loops, best of 3: 28.2 ms per loop

# Original soln
In [82]: %timeit [np.nonzero(i > arr)[0][-1] for i in values]
100 loops, best of 3: 8.68 ms per loop

# From this post
In [83]: %timeit np.searchsorted(arr,values)-1
10000 loops, best of 3: 57.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: Nice solution and timing :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Use broadcast and `argmin`

```
np.argmin(values > arr[:,None], axis=0) - 1

Out[32]: array([0, 2, 1], dtype=int32)
```

*Note*: I assume `arr` is monotonic increasing as in the sample

Comment: That seems to do the trick. I'm not sure I understand how that works. I'm not familiar with using the slice with "None" [:,None]

Comment: @RichColburn: it is a short way of adding/expand an addition dimension to an array to use with numpy broadcasting. It is equivalent to `np.expand_dims(arr, axis=1)`. Read docs on `expand_dims` for more info(note: `newaxis`  in the docs of `expand_dims` is just alias of `None`): https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html